# ftp - Unable to connect to Upstart:

Tags: upstart, vsftpd

Trying to set up an ftp server on a new install to accept files.  `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is in place and `write_enable=YES`.

It is not working and when I go to restart `vsftpd` , I get the following error.

> Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

This is 16.04 on a HP Pavilion desktop.  Oddly, I set this up on a lap top running 16.04 not that long ago.

**Any idea on how to correct?** 
I'm following: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Using a different command, it appears it is running but the terminal ends with that odd last line with `(END)` and locks up.

I don't know what that means:

```
dan@Pavilion:~$ service vsftpd status
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-07-03 08:11:57 PDT; 1 day 5h ago
 Main PID: 975 (vsftpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
           └─975 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf

Jul 03 08:11:57 Pavilion systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Jul 03 08:11:57 Pavilion systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
lines 1-9/9 (END)
```

Comment: Ubuntu uses systemd now. which ubuntu version are you running!

Comment: This is 16.04 on a HP Pavilion desktop. Oddly, I set this up on a lap top running 16.04 not that long ago. Any idea on how to correct? I'm following: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Comment: Using a different command, it appears it i srunning

Comment: How did you try to restart? The `(END)` only means that it has reached the end of the output/log file for this service. As you can see in `Active: active(running)` the service is running already.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu use now systemd. So if you want to restart `vsftpd` use this command:

```
service vsftpd restart
```